# Cassandra public IP not connecting

Tags: cassandra

I'm using cassandra in ubuntu server. when I try to connect using CLI with public IP address, It returns connection refused. whereas If I tried with localhost, its working fine. I made the configuration changes in cassandra.yaml and storage-conf.xml. but still I have the problem. What change should be done ?

Thanks in advance..

s..I have connecting the server using ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Changing localhost to 0.0.0.0 in cassandra.yaml is not always work. In case of JVM Implementation is different ,it wont work

Check`cassandra-env.sh`file  and make this entry at last along with `JVM_OPTS` options

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=here your IP"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your firewall settings on the server to make sure connections are allowed to Cassandra?

Answer (score 0):

vi conf/cassandra.yaml and edit localhost to 0.0.0.0