# Can't start Cassandra server with public IP(Port 7000 error)

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I'm seting up cassandra server on centos 6.8 and change to public IP
by using https://stackoverflow.com/a/17164723/10206109 method but it stuck when start server with cassandra -f -R and I got this error:

```
ERROR [main] 2019-09-10 11:42:31,684 CassandraDaemon.java:749 - Fatal 
configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Unable to bind to 
address /<public ip>:7000. Set listen_address in cassandra.yaml to an 
interface you can bind to, e.g., your private IP address on EC2
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.getServerSockets(MessagingService.java:739) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.listen(MessagingService.java:681) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.listen(MessagingService.java:665) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:796) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:683) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:632) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:388) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:620) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:732) [apache-cassandra-3.11.4.jar:3.11.4]
```

I try to change in /cassandra.yaml

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
listen_address: <public ip>
broadcast_rpc_address: <public ip>
```

but it still stuck in this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rpc_address` and `broadcast_rpc_address` are the addresses for clients, but you need to configure internode communication instead.

The [DataStax documentation says](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/config/configSnitchEC2MultiRegion.html) (same for OSS Cassandra):

> 1. In the `cassandra.yaml`, set the `listen_address` to the **private IP address** of the node, and the `broadcast_address` to the **public IP address** of the node. This allows DataStax Enterprise nodes in one EC2 region to bind to nodes in another region, thus enabling multiple datacenter support. For intra-region traffic, DataStax Enterprise switches to the private IP after establishing a connection.
> 2. Set the addresses of the seed nodes in the `cassandra.yaml` file to that of the **public IP**. *Private IP are not routable between networks*. For example:

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have save my day. But in listen_address I use localhost instead my private IP. Private IP doesn't work. Anyway thanks for your advice.